# RabbitMQ C# API: How to check if a binding exists?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, messaging

Using the RabbitMQ C# API, how would I check to see if a binding exists from a given queue to a given exchange?

A lot of RabbitMQ calls are idempotent, so some people may say that the check is unnecessary for those cases, but I think they would be useful in testing.

Comment: If amqp doesn't let you check this, you can use rabbit's rest api http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_5/priv/www/api/index.html In particular, the `bindings` function returns a full list of existing bindings.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping I could use the C# API to do it, but if that's not an option, I will try out your suggestion.

Comment: Not through the client API.  But, maybe the management API: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use their REST API to call and see if the binding exists.

You have a local copy of the API reference at: `your_server_name:15672/api/`  or you can find it at [their online docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)

You can make a `GET` call to either:

- `/api/exchanges/vhost`
- `/name/bindings/destination`

with the appropriate substitutions in there for vhost or name.

Or you could just call:

- `/api/bindings`

to get all of them.

From there, you'll need to parse the JSON object that is returned.

Note, you will likely need to authenticate but their examples show how to do so.