# RabbitMQ and Spring: how to get all subscriptions

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, stomp, sockjs

I'm using RabbitMQ, Spring and SockJS.
My app generatea many different messages and posts them to rabbitmq via stomp. This generation requires a lot of resources so I want to know is there any subscriptions to rabbitmq and what kind of subscription it is (I need to know routing keys of this subscriptions) to avoid generating unnecessary messages.
Is there any possibilities to get this information from Spring or any Java client library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ C# API: How to check if a binding exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046053/rabbitmq-c-sharp-api-how-to-check-if-a-binding-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library to get information from rabbitmq http api https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the information using one or more of the following

- [command line tool rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)
- [rabbitmq http api](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html)
- [rabbitmq management (web ui)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)